# Diff b/w mediation2.2 & mediation3.3 in Business studio ActiveMatrix BPM

Tags: tibco

I am new to tibco. Could I please have the differences between mediation2.2 and mediation3.0 with regards to implementation and deployment in Business studio ActiveMatrix BPM?

Regards,

Abhi

Answer (score 2):

It refers to medtiation service units which do messag etransformation and routing. The thing is AMX BPM is built over Active Matrix Service Grid 3.0 base. The earlier version of AMX SG was 2.3 which used a completely different architecture. In order to make AMX BPM orchestrate services of both 2.3 and 3.0  this bifurcation was made.

Regards,
Gaurav